# google charts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-api

I am using google charts in my test application. But I am getting this error

> "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'nodeName' of null
>       at Object.ElementsFilter.isOnIgnoreList (chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/contentscript.js:76:34)
>       at chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/contentscript.js:318:28
>       at parseContent (chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/contentscript.js:316:14)
>       at processSettingsResponse (chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/contentscript.js:551:9)
>       at chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/browserSpecificScript.js:77:9"

I googled about this but could not understand what the issue is. My code is:

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="static/lib/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//google.com/jsapi"></script>



</head>


<body onload = onLoading()>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BNG Subscriber Analytics</a>
            </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i1"></canvas></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i2"></canvas></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i3" ></canvas></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i4" ></canvas></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i5" ></canvas></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i6" ></canvas></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i7" ></canvas></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3"><canvas id="i8" ></canvas></div>
    </div>


</body>



<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoading()

{          
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
}
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('i1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }            

</script>
```